# Proving point is not Lyapunov-stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I am having some problems with the following question:

> Show that the origin is not Lyapunov-stable for the differential equation $x'=x^3$

Now, if we solve for the flow $\phi_t(x)$, we obtain that

$$\phi_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} - 2t}}$$

A point $x_0$ is Lyapunov-stable if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ where $|\phi_t(x) - \phi_t(x_0)| <\epsilon$ if $|x - x_0| < \delta$

My problem is that $\phi_t(x)$ is not even defined at $x = 0$, so how can I go about disproving this? (Or is this fact enough?)

Comment: *Your formula* for the flow is only valid for $x \neq 0$ (well, actually only for $x>0$, since it has the wrong sign for $x<0$), but the flow itself is defined for all $x$. Since $x=0$ is an equilibrium point, obviously $\phi_t(0)=0$ for all $t$. You can incorporate this case into your formula (and correct the sign error too) if you rewrite it as $\phi_t(x)=x/\sqrt{1-2tx^2}$.

Comment: OH, so then I have to get the formula for all $x$ and work from there. Thank you so much! This answered my main concern.

Comment: $x(t) = \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{1-2x^2_0t}}$. Clearly it is defined at $x_0=0$. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432149/stability-of-solution/2768270#2768270

Answer (score 2):

The origin is not stable for the following reason: Since $x'=x^3$, solutions starting at any $x_1\neq 0$ get farther and farther away from the origin ($x'(t)>0$ if $x_1>0$  or $x'(t)<0$ if $x_1< 0$). In other words, solutions starting arbitrarily close to the stationary solution $x=0$ do not stay close for all $t>0$. Given any $\varepsilon>0$, no matter what $\delta>0$ we choose, for any $x_1$ with $0<|x_1|<\delta$ we have $|x(t)|>\varepsilon$ for $t>t_0$.

Comment: Ok, but if I want to prove for example that, on the other hand, $x' = -x^3$ is stable at the origin, I end up with the same problem that $\phi_t(x)$ is not defined there, so how can I even start showing that the relationship between both inequalities holds?

Comment: In this case, your field is pointing towards the origin. You do not have to find your flow, just observe that if you start at $x_1\neq 0$, your distance to the origin can only decrease as $t\to\infty$ and you can choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ (if you start within a $\delta$ distance from the origin, you will always be within that distance). BTW  the flow is given by $x(t)=\pm 1/\sqrt{2t+k}$ with $k=1/x_1^2$ in this case, with $+$ sign if $x_1>0$ and $-$ sign if $x_1<0$. I think your notation for this flow is $\phi_t(x_1)$.

Comment: Ok, yes I understand. But then, how does the definition of Lyapunov-stability make sense if in this case the differences are not even defined since the denominator is $0$? I am trying to prove it using the definition.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "the denominator is $0$". The formula for the general solution does not include the trivial solution. Any other solution, starting at $x_1\neq 0$ is given by this formula and is well defined for all $t\in[0,\infty)$ and they all approach $0$ as $t\to \infty$. Your $\phi_t(0)$ is just zero and the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition can be readily verified, you just get rid of $t$ and by choosing $\delta=\varepsilon$ your definition is satisfied, as it was clear from the qualitative reasoning above.

Comment: Assume we are talking about the ODE $x' = -x^3$ and I want to show stability of $x = 0$ using the definition. Then, at some point we need to evaluate $\phi_t(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{0} - 2t}}$ and here we have a $0$ in the denominator of a fraction. Most surely, I am misunderstanding something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: You cannot use that formula to find $\phi_t(0)$. This one is a special solution, not given by the general formula. It is just $\phi_t(0)=0$ for all $t\ge 0$. Then $|\phi_t(x_1)-\phi_t(0)|=|\phi_t(x_1)|=1/\sqrt{-2t+1/x_1^2}$. You want to prove instability. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. We prove that no $\delta$ works for that $\varepsilon$. Let $\|x_1-x_0|=|x_1|<\delta$. Then $|\phi_t(x_1)|>1/\sqrt{-2t+1/\delta^2}>\varepsilon$ for $t$ close enough to $1/2\delta^2$ (just solve the inequality for $t$). This contradicts stability. What we are saying is that solutions eventually blow up.