# Stability of autonomous system $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(y)$$

Is critical point $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ semi-stable?

Because according to "Zill engineering math 6th", it says semi-stable means one side diverge to infinity and other side converge case.
However, $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ case is one side converges to $\frac{5\pi}{2}$ and other side converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

How can I define stability of that critical point?

Comment: One side would converge to $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, not $2\pi$ if I am understanding you correctly. That would make this critical point unstable, not semistable.

Comment: Oh I edit it. You mean "even thought both side goes to infinity, it could be unstable". right?

Comment: Unstable means that both sides avoid the critical point. That is what happens here.

Comment: Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432149/stability-of-solution/2768270#2768270